# Is there a way to add a continuous placeholder in vs code snippets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I created a simple js snippet for objects:

```
"object": {
        "prefix": "ob",
        "body": [
            "const ${1} = {",
            "",
                "${2}: ${3},",
            "",
            "};",
        ],
        "description": "object"
    },
```

I want it to continue to add names and values until I stop writing, not just one name and value like my snippets.

Comment: 1) Show what you searched for (your search queries). It can help future users find this question. 2) Not an answer, but how bad is it really to just copy-paste and edit?

Comment: split in 2 snippets, create a snippet for a key-value pair, place the cursor `${0}` at the correct location for next kv-pair